# How to make the RecyclerView forbid Scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

In some cases, we need to make the RecyclerView cannot scroll, so play to your strengths for this questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have some solutions for this problem, hope it can help you.See below for details:

1. void setLayoutFrozen (boolean frozen);[image: method details]
   **I strongly recommend if we only want to inhabit scroll** for this scheme for its simplicity and convenience; [if you want to know deeply](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)
2. When we use **LayoutManager**(LinearManager or GridLayoutManager), we can use this.

`

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 

LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false){

        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
            return super.canScrollHorizontally();
        }
    };`
```

GridLayoutManager is alike.

3. From above second item, we can extend corresponding LayoutManager.

`

```
public class MyGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

public MyGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
    super(context, spanCount);
}
public MyGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public MyGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
    this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
}
}
```

`
4. We can handle the RecyclerView TouchEvent to achieve the effect.

From above, I believe you can make yourself. Good Luck...

Comment: BTW, I can't agree more with this sentence: **It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! — phrase it in the form of a question.**